# Installing in a file system that does not support symlinks

Tags: windows, symlink, autoconf, automake, libtool

I have a project using **autoconf**, **automake** and **libtool**. I have configured it with `--prefix=/some/directory`, and `/some/directory` is unfortunately mounted on a filesystem that does not support symlinks, resulting in errors.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libblas.so': Read-only file system
```

Is there a way to prevent make install from using symlinks, but rather use copies?

Comment: It's reporting a 'read-only file system' - either this error isn't accurate, or you don't have permission to write to the device - which is a more immediate problem than the file system type.

Comment: Writing to the filesystem works though. This is a NTFS filesystem mounted to a directory using VirtualBox driver.

Comment: Hm, the host OS is Windows, I doubt that, but I will take your suggestion.

Comment: I guess that's not it. I was thinking you were running a Linux/BSD, and using an NTFS file system. OS X, for example, will only mount NTFS file systems as read-only by default.